# WP7 Emulator and Fiddler

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, fiddler

I know there are a LOT of blog posts on this. But I can't seem to find an answer. I'm trying to debug an application that communicates with some services I have running locally. Right now, I have two services. One of them works. One of them does not. Both are running in http://localhost:90. To help me resolve this, I turned to Fiddler.

Oddly, Fiddler shows traffic in Internet Explorer in the emulator, but it does not show traffic from my application. With my application running, I launch Fiddler and nothing appears. I do not see any traffic. I have been able to confirm that I am successfully accessing the one service. However, no traffic appears in Fiddler. To see if Http traffic is running, I exited my Silverlight application and started Internet Explorer on the emulator. When I visit websites in IE on the emulator, I see traffic being written to Fiddler.

I'm totally confused. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type of web server or platform are your services running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually configure Fiddler to be able to access `localhost`. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottcate/archive/2008/05/22/working-with-fiddler-on-localhost.aspx) is a workaround that needs to be done in the application.

Basically, what you need is the extra dot when accessing the location. So in your case it will be:

```
http://localhost.:90
```

Also, you might want to try some additional [config settings](http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic).

Comment: I've tried referencing http://localhost.:90 and http://mymachine:90 without any luck. This is so weird. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try the config settings?

Comment: When you say "Without any luck" do you mean that the traffic worked but you couldn't see it? Or do you mean that it didn't work?

Comment: I mean, I can see traffic through the browser in the WP7 emulator. However, I do not see any traffic from my app running within the WP7 emulator. Very strange.